# Guzzle request for getting Youtube LiveChatMessages list

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-data-api, guzzle, google-apis-explorer

I'm working with Youtube Data API and trying to get chat messages, for that I have to provide `lifeChatId` and `part` parameters

My code

```
    $guzzle_client = new Client();
    $res = $guzzle_client->request('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages',
        [
           'liveChatId' => $broadcastsResponse['modelData']['snippet']['liveChatId'],
           'part' => 'id,snippet'
        ]
    );
```

I'm getting error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: liveChatId",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "liveChatId"
   },
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: part",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: liveChatId"
 }
}
```

But I'm sure I provide both required parameters.
This var_dump written right before guzzle request

```
var_dump([
    'liveChatId' => $broadcastsResponse['modelData']['snippet']['liveChatId'],
    'part' => 'id,snippet'
]);)
```

returns

```
array(2) {
  ["liveChatId"]=>
  string(20) "Cg0KC2hRYmU3akNyaXBV"
  ["part"]=>
  string(10) "id,snippet"
}
```

Have any idea why I get such error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing them as query string parameters, using the `query` request option.

```
$guzzle_client = new Client();
$liveChatId = $broadcastsResponse['modelData']['snippet']['liveChatId'];

$res = $guzzle_client->request('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveChat/messages', [
    'query' => ['liveChatId' => $liveChatId, 'part' => 'id,snippet']
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked for me!